# Буква Я при считывании на Си

Tags: файлы, c++

**Проблема такая, я считываю строку из файла вот этим кодом**

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
char path[]="1.txt";
FILE* fp = fopen(path, "r");
unsigned int N = 10, delta=10, i = 0; 
char* s = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*N); 
if (fp)
{
    while ((s [i] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF  )  {                
        if (++i >= N) {
            N += delta;
            s = (char*) realloc (s, sizeof(char)*N);        
        }   
    } 
    fclose(fp);
    s[i] = '\0';
} else { printf("Входной файл отсутствует\n"); exit(1); }
```

Но он считывается до первой буквы "Я " в чём дело?

Comment: Сам ты панда, я разобрался символ Я равен символу EOF , поэтому надо смотреть не по символу конца файла а по концу потока т.е на до юзать
while (feof(fp))

Comment: @Даниил Демченко, Вам правильно советуют. Используйте для считывания символа не переменную типа `char`, а `int`. Тогда такой проблемы не будет. Все дело в том, что EOF определен как "-1", что в однобайтовой кодировке неотличимо от символа 'я' с кодом 255 (0xFF).

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );
```

Вот так русскую локализацию ставь, панда.
Если все равно неудача, то вместо **char** используй **wchar_t**, в ней у тебя гарантированно сохранится символ расширенной таблицы кодировки.